# Node.js - Display image from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I managed to save image to mongoDB with type Buffer. Together with the image is the username of the user currently logged in. MY problem now is to display the image(s) to the client's side. Much appreciated if it has a condition like "display image where username = 'currentUser_username'". I also have an 'uploads' folder where the images are saved. Please help. I'm a newbie in nodeJS. Please be very detailed in ur answer. Thanks

Comment: post some code or the logic you have tried so far...

Comment: Just place the url on the `<img src={"data-url-here"} />, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send the image to the client, you need to save image binary data, image content type.

The structure of your schema should be like this.

```
var demoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    imageData : { type: Buffer },
    imageType : {type: String },
    imageName : {type: String }
})

mongoose.model('Demo', demoSchema)
```

On saving your image to DB, save the content type too (must).

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(incomingImage.path);
var input = new Demo():
input.image = new MongoDb.Binary(data);
input.imageType = incomingImage.type;
input.imageName = incomingImage.name;

input.save();
```

When you retrieve from DB and send the contentType and mention the buffer as binary to the client.

```
Demo.findById(req.params.id, function (error, result) {
    res.contentType(result.imageType);    
    res.end(result.image.buffer, "binary");
});
```

If you need some brief detail see [here](http://blog.datafiddle.net/?p=729158)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers. These are all helpful. I'll try all of these :)